# sidekiq perform_in perform_at is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am using Sidekiq

on my gemfile I have:

```
#gemfile 
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 6.0.7'
```

Now my model looks like

```
class Special < ActiveRecord::Base
  def set_queue
    if send_at.present? # send at is a data time
      SpecialQueueClientsJob.perform_at(self.send_at, self)
    end
  end
end
```

This is the code to my job and this works perfect when I just call it normally `SpecialQueueClientsJob.perform_later(special: self)`

```
class SpecialQueueClientsJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default
  def perform(special)
    ...
  end
end
```

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq

I am getting an error `undefined method` perform_at' for SpecialQueueClientsJob `

I am looking at https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs

> Sidekiq allows you to schedule the time when a job will be executed.
> You use perform_in(interval_in_seconds, *args) or
> perform_at(timestamp, *args) rather than the standard
> perform_async(*args):
>
> MyWorker.perform_in(3.hours, 'mike', 1)
> MyWorker.perform_at(3.hours.from_now, 'mike', 1) This is useful for
> example if you want to send the user an email 3 hours after they sign
> up. Jobs which are scheduled in the past are enqueued for immediate
> execution.

Comment: I assume you are using ActiveJob, the Sidekiq API does not apply.